# How to get consensus sequence from BAM file format on java (by means of Picard)

Tags: java, media, picard

How can I view the Picard BAM file format using Java?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://picard.sourceforge.net/ - this is a Java library for SAM and BAM Picard files, and its on SourceForge so the source code should be available to you.